# python - delete rows and and assign their value to other rows

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

In python I have a database with this structure:

`python`

| Group | Subgroup | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A_1 | 10 |
| A | A_2 | 15 |
| A | A_X | 30 |
| B | B_1 | 10 |
| B | B_2 | 15 |
| B | B_3 | 20 |
| B | B_X | 60 |
| C | C_1 | 1 |
| C | C_X | 4 |
| C | C_2 | 1 |
| C | C_3 | 1 |
| C | C_4 | 1 |

The number of subgroups varies depending on the group to which it belongs.

I need to get the following:

`python`

| Group | Subgroup | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A_1 | 25 |
| A | A_2 | 30 |
| B | B_1 | 30 |
| B | B_2 | 35 |
| B | B_3 | 40 |
| C | C_1 | 2 |
| C | C_2 | 2 |
| C | C_3 | 2 |
| C | C_4 | 2 |

Basically I have to remove the subgroups ending with "X" and distribute the value equally to the other subgroups (within the same group).

Do you have any idea how I can do this, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Group','Subgroup'])
def transform(x):
    x['Value'] = x['Value'] + x.iloc[-1]['Value'] / (len(x) - 1)
    return x.iloc[:-1]
df = df.groupby('Group').apply(transform).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
  Group Subgroup  Value
0     A      A_1   25.0
1     A      A_2   30.0
2     B      B_1   30.0
3     B      B_2   35.0
4     B      B_3   40.0
5     C      C_1    2.0
6     C      C_2    2.0
7     C      C_3    2.0
8     C      C_4    2.0
```

Comment: need to add `df.sort_values(by='Subgroup', inplace=True)` before `df = df.groupby()`

Comment: That's the first line of the snippet. @BlackRaven

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: If I have two columns of values (Value and Value2 for example) how do I change the def formula?Would that be ok?: def transform(x,y): (x['Value'],y['Value2']) = (x['Value'],y['Value2']) + ((x.iloc[-1]['Value']),(y.iloc[-1]['Value2'])) / ((len(x) - 1),(len(y) - 1)) return (x.iloc[:-1]),(y.iloc[:-1])